# Problem with EventListener to create a RGB color palette with JS

Tags: javascript, event-listener

i'm trying to create a palette of color with 2 block. My problem is that my code give me thoose blocks with the same color, how can i separate the two to make two distinct color ? I hope i am clear my english is not that good. Thanks in advance!

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const blockone = document.querySelector("#block1");
const blocktwo = document.querySelector("#block2");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  const newColor = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`
  blockone.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
  blockone.innerText = newColor

  const r2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  const g2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  const b2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  const newColor2 = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`
  blocktwo.style.backgroundColor = newColor2;
  blocktwo.innerText = newColor2

})
```

```html
<div id="block1"></div>
<div id="block2"></div>
<button>click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code. Replace 'const newColor2 = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`' with 'const newColor2 = `rgb(${r2}, ${g2}, ${b2})`'